# Where to keep an object instance that I want to share across multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture

I'm architecturing a game in C# & xaml using MVVM. This game consists of a main menu with a new game option. The new game button takes you to a Player Select page where you can type the names of the two players and select if it's a player vs player game or a player vs computer game. Then you arrive at the game screen and play the game.

My question is, I am keeping persistent info in a `Game` object which contains properties such as `Player Player1` and `Player Player 2` and `ReactiveCollection<Tile> Tiles`, etc. Should I just make the `Game` instance static and be done or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `static` is not testable. Your code would be better split off into modules and the game container can resolve what objects need what modules.

Comment: @Romoku I don't want to make it static, but I can't think of a better way right now. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [Dependency Injection By Hand](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand). That should give you a good start as to how to handle making modules.

Comment: Yes and I don't think you want to keep your game engine in your UI layer (MVVM). Instead you may want your Model to query the game engine (Player, Tiles, etc.) about its current state and display it to the user. Separation of concerns between your UI and the persistence of your game state.

Comment: Read this - it's about singletons rather than simply static variables, but the point's the same: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html#what-we-can-do-instead

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Game service.

```
public interface IGameService
{
    Player PlayerOne { get; set; }
    Player PlayerTwo { get; set; }
    Tiles ReactiveCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Then your service can be resolved to a class using IOC / Dependency injection when your viewmodels/app are created.  That way you can create a singleton of the service class that can be used by any viewmodel, but it is sitll decoupled and testable.  Then the class that implements your IGameService can get is information/data from the game however it wants which also makes it flexible.  You can change the way the information is delivered without having to change the viewmodels that consume that service.